# C++ program has stopped working- Solving ordinary differential equations

Tags: c++, vector, crash, ode, differential-equations

I'm writing a C++ program to find solutions for first order differential equations for a college assignment. The program starts up and then once I enter the number of iterations to do I get the error message "Euler's method.exe has stopped working". This is my code:

```html
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

 
double f_r(double x, double r) {  
  return r;
  } 

double f_s(double x, double s) {
  return -x/s;  
  }
 

double eulerstep(const function<double(double,double)>& f, double xsub0, double ysub0, double h) {
  double ysub1 = ysub0+ h * f(xsub0,ysub0);
  return ysub1;
  }


double euler(const function<double(double,double)>& f, double xsub0, double ysub0, double h, int n) {
  vector<double> xsub;
  vector<double> ysub;
  xsub[0] = xsub0;
  ysub[0] = ysub0;
  n = ysub.size();
  for (int i=1; i<n; i++){
   xsub[i+1] = xsub[i] + h;
   ysub[i+1] = ysub[i] + h * f(xsub[i],ysub[i]);
   cout << xsub[i] << " , " << ysub[i] << endl;
  }
  return ysub[n];
  }
  
int main() {
  int nsteps = 0;
  cout << "Number of steps?" << endl;
  cin >> nsteps;
  double h = 1.0 / nsteps;

  double r = euler(f_r,0,1,h,nsteps);
  

  double s = euler(f_s,0,1,h,nsteps);
 
  return 0;
}
```

I'm fairly sure the problem lies in how I've defined my vectors but I'm new to using them so can't see where I've gone wrong. I'd be extremely grateful if anyone could point out the mistakes in my method

Thanks

Comment: How far do you get when you run this in a debugger?

Comment: You can add items to vector using `push_back()`

Comment: `xsub[0] = xsub0;` there starts your problem

Comment: It asks for the number of steps and when I put in any number it crashes and then the process exits with a very high return value

Comment: not related to the problem at hand, but you should include <iostream> when you plan on using cout and cin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vector assignment crashing, not sure why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40552250/vector-assignment-crashing-not-sure-why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated function.  You have to set the sizes, not ask an empty vector for its size.

```
double euler(const function<double(double, double)>& f, double xsub0, double ysub0, double h, int n)
{
    vector<double> xsub;
    vector<double> ysub;
    xsub.resize(n+1); // so we can access [n], it must be size n+1
    ysub.resize(n+1);
    xsub[0] = xsub0;
    ysub[0] = ysub0;
    for (int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
        xsub[i + 1] = xsub[i] + h;
        ysub[i + 1] = ysub[i] + h * f(xsub[i], ysub[i]);
        cout << xsub[i] << " , " << ysub[i] << endl;
    }
    return ysub[n];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<double> xsub;
vector<double> ysub;
```

You are instantiating a pair of vectors. They are initially empty.

```
xsub[0] = xsub0;
ysub[0] = ysub0;
```

You then proceed to assign values to the contents of the vector. This is where you crash, because the vectors are empty, and contain no values.

`vector[x]` references an existing element in a vector. The vector must already have at least `x+1` elements in them, but none of your vectors have anything in them. They do not have element 0, nor element 1, nor any element.

Looks like your code expects each vector to contain `n+1` elements, so you should explicitly invoke each vector's `resize()` method, accordingly, before you attempt to use each vector.