# Transpose of a 2D matrix using vectors in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I am trying to find out the transpose of a 2D matrix using vectors. The following code is not working for me. I am trying to pass the matrix into a function named transpose(). What are the other ways I can do it? I appreciate if you point out my errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void transpose(vector<vector<int> > &b)
{
    vector<vector<int> > trans_vec;

    for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<b[i].size();j++)
        {
            trans_vec[j][i]=b[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int> > v1;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        vector<int> temp;
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            temp.push_back(i);
        }
        v1.push_back(temp);
    }
    //Display output
    for(int i=0;i<v1.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<v1[i].size();j++)
        {
            cout<<v1[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    transpose(v1);
    //display transposed matrix
    for(int i=0;i<v1.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<v1[i].size();j++)
        {
            cout<<v1[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a canonical duplicate of "use C++ vector before resizing"...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ program has stopped working- Solving ordinary differential equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191605/c-program-has-stopped-working-solving-ordinary-differential-equations)

Comment: [Alternative possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40552250/vector-assignment-crashing-not-sure-why). @user202729 Of course, SO has all the questions.

Comment: trans_vec is local variable that is getting changed inside function and nothing is returned from this function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are leaving the passed in parameter untouched. That's why you see no change.
Also, you're accessing invalid indices, so initialize the vector with the right size. Try this:

```
void transpose(vector<vector<int> > &b)
{
    if (b.size() == 0)
        return;

    vector<vector<int> > trans_vec(b[0].size(), vector<int>());

    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b[i].size(); j++)
        {
            trans_vec[j].push_back(b[i][j]);
        }
    }

    b = trans_vec;    // <--- reassign here
}
```

This initializes the vector to the right size in the first line.
Of course this only works, if b[0].size() == b[1].size() == ... == b[n].size().

If you don't want to use push_back you could write:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < b[i].size(); j++)
    {
        if (trans_vec[j].size() != b.size())
            trans_vec[j].resize(b.size());
        trans_vec[j][i] = b[i][j];
    }
```

Another way to return the result would be to return trans_vec at the end of the function and pass in b as a const reference:

```
vector<vector<int> > transpose(const vector<vector<int> > &b)
{
     ...
     return trans_vec;
}
```

Comment: i have made the necessary changes. But my code is getting stuck at the point where it comes to declaring the size of tran_vec inside the function transpose()

Comment: Of course, edited my answer :)

Comment: Thanks so much :). Just a quick question. What does b[0].size do?

Comment: b[0].size() is the size (number of entries) of the first vector (row) in b. Since we're transposing the matrix, the number of rows for the resulting matrix must be equal to the number of columns of the input matrix (b) :) Hope that makes sense.