# combining "columns" in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays:

```
var arr = [
    [0, 3, 3],
    [0, 4, 3],
    [1, 3, 4],
    [1, 4, 4]
];
```

I want to create a new array that combines the contents of each index of the inner arrays. For example, the first elements at index 0 of each of the inner arrays are 0, 0, 1, and 1. I want to create a new array that combines those elements so that I end up with [0, 1] (I don't want duplicates in the new array). The next "column" is 3, 4, 3, and 4. So I'd want an array of [3, 4].

The end result I want is

```
[
    [0, 1],
    [3, 4],
    [3, 4]
]
```

I can't quite figure out how to do this.

Comment: Hey @XtevensChannel, please checkout this link (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a StackOverflow question. I'd recommend posting code you've already tried so we can try to help fix any mistakes you may have made.

Comment: From your answer you're looking to remove duplicates and then transpose the matrix. I'd first transpose (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49444856/transpose-of-a-2d-matrix-using-vectors-in-c/49445850) and then remove duplicates (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935662/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-array/50935882).

Answer (score 1):

May not be the most efficient, but does meet you cryptic requirements.

```
    var arr = [
    [0, 3, 3],
    [0, 4, 3],
    [1, 3, 4],
    [1, 4, 4]
];

const unique = (myArray) => [...new Set(myArray)];

let x, y,
    tarr = [],  // temp array
    farr = [];  // final array

for (x=0; x<arr.length; x++) {
  tarr.length = 0;
  for (y=0; y<arr[x].length; y++) {
    tarr.push(arr[y][x])
  }
  farr.push( unique(tarr) );
}
console.log(farr.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here another solution.

```js
const result = (arr) => {

let index = 0;
  const min = Math.min(...arr.map(r => r.length)) // get min length
  const grid = [];

  while (index < min) { // loop with min
    let s = new Set(); // using set to keep unique values
    arr.forEach(r => s.add(r[index])); // pick value
    grid.push([...s]); // get array from set
    index++;
  }
  
  return grid
}

const array = [ [0, 3, 3], [0, 4, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 4] ];

console.log(result(array))
```